# Laravel - Session e Array

Tags: array, laravel, session

Estou precisando fazer criar um array:

```
array(
   0 => 0,
   1 => 0,
   2 => 1,
   3 => 0,
   4 => 0,
   5 => 1,
   6 => 0)
```

dentro de um session:

```
session('session_array')
```

e depois adicionar e resgatar individualmente os valores de acordo com cada key do array. Como faço isso? Não consegui entender muito bem vendo a documentação do laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso você esteja utilizando o Laravel 4

A sessão é criada da seguinte forma:

```
Session::put('key',['um','dois']);
```

para exibir os dados `Session::get('key.um')`

Para o laravel 5

para criar

```
session()->put('key','value');
```

para exibir

```
session()->get('key');
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer adicionar esses array em uma valor da sessão onde você já tinha inserido agum dado, a melhor forma seria usar o método `push`

```
session()->put('session_array', 1);

session->push('session_array', 2);

session->push('session_array', 2);

var_dump(session('session_array')); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Você também pode definir o `array` diretamente na `key` específica:

```
session()->put('session_array', $array)
```

Você também pode acessar definir valores através da notação por ponto:

```
 session('session_array.nome', 'Wallace');
 session('session_array.1', 10);
 session('session_array.2', 20);
```

Alternativamente você também pode definir um `array` diretamente:

```
session(['session_array' => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Para pegar os valores, você pode fazer das seguintes forma:

```
  //equivale a $_SESSION['session_array']['name']

 session('session_array.name'); 

 session('session_array.1');
```

Comment: `session('session_array.name')` está retornando o array todo.

Comment: Nesse caso, você deve ter definido o `array` nele todo.

Comment: Ele está retornando: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1)`